# How to place the multiple table values in thyme-leaf view html file?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I can retrieve the values from multiple tables in database, but in thyme leaf html tags i don't know how to place the retrieved values in view page. Can anyone please give me a sample code using html with thyme leaf tags for showing 2 table values?

(spring mvc, hibernate, MySQL, thyme-leaf)

Comment: Please show your source code, what have you done sofar?

Comment: i got result to controller but from controll i kept in sessin as we did in jsp but in jsp view i am geeting data.but where as in thymeleaf view i am not geeting result please help me thanks in advanceeeeee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a sample method to pass values form a controller to a template:

```
public String index(Model model, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest req) {
    model.addAttribute("cars", this.cars);
    return "index";
}
```

This is a possible snippet to access for example a car-list:

```
<th:block th:each="car: ${cars}">
      <span th:text="${car.name}"/>
</th:block>
```

Comment: i am retrieving two table value so you better to give sample code using two tables.  ---thanks

Comment: what kind of type have the table values? Please post more code.